# Open Browser From Haskell Interpreter

Tags: browser, haskell, io, ghci

I've been messing around a lot with oeis.org, I found a module on Hackage that provides an interface to oeis.org (Math.OEIS), but it displays its results on the command line. I was wondering if anyone knew how to go about opening a url in the default browser from ghci.

Thanks

Comment: Well, I'm assuming there is some kind of library somewhere that handles making system calls. have you tried to start it via a shell/system call? From the command-line it is not too difficult to launch _a_ browser, and depending on the OS, it may be able to launch the default (debian & ubuntu have `sensible-browser` for this purpose)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I use:

```
-- | Attempt to open a web browser on the given url, all platforms.
openBrowserOn :: String -> IO ExitCode
```

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hledger-1.22.2/docs/src/Hledger.Cli.Utils.html#openBrowserOn

20110630: see [wai-handler-launch](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-handler-launch) ([blog post](http://www.yesodweb.com/show/topic/348)) for more robust code.